# issue on running services in ionic 4 android version9

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using Ionic 4  from android version 9 api/webservices are not working. Even i change the config.xml edit-config file
And also changes done 
    domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false"  but not working

Answer (score 0):

Android 8+ are now forced to use https requests for security reasons. Check that your link is https, and if it didn't work then for sure the problem is from your request and you don't have to change any thing in config or anywhere place, just change tour api from http to https.